# Confusion about reading xml file

Tags: asp.net, linq, listview

I am trying to retrieve some data from  my xml file to a listview .I am a little bit confused.This is what i have so far .How can do it  .Thanks in advance

```
XDocument doc=XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("PhoneBook.xml"));
var q = from c in doc.Descendants("Persons") select new
{ 
    name=c.Element("Name"),
    phone=c.Element("Phone"),
};

foreach (var item in q)
{
    var lvi = new ListViewItem(item.name);
}
```

Comment: What error(s) are you receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIrst part of your code looks good. You don't need the foreach loop. Here's how your code should look like:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("PhoneBook.xml"));
var q = from c in doc.Descendants("Persons")
        select new
        {

            name = c.Element("Name"),
            phone = c.Element("Phone"),
        };

ListView1.DataSource = q;
ListView1.DataBind();
```

In markup you can bind any template field with name or phone. Your ListView may look like this:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table runat="server" id="table1">
            <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder">
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
            <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server"
                    Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' />
            </td>
            <td id="Td2" runat="server">
                <asp:Label ID="PhoneLabel" runat="server"
                    Text='<%#Eval("Phone") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

And this layout will produce this type of output:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to predict without a sample XML but I noticed you were missing the "Root" element and based on that the next item to navigate are the elements inside of "Root:

```
XDocument doc=XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("PhoneBook.xml"));    

var items = (from item in doc.Root.Elements("Persons") 
select new {     
    name=c.Element("Name"),
    phone=c.Element("Phone"),
};
```

If this is not the answer, please share a sample of your XML this will help us to provide a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

First change your code like this because you assign Name and Phone to XElement, not Element Value:

```
var q = from c in doc.Descendants("Persons") 
    select new { 
                 name=c.Element("Name").Value,
                 phone=c.Element("Phone").Value
               };
```

Then try this code:

```
listView1.View = View.Details;
listView1.Columns.Add("Person Name", 200, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Phone Number", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

foreach (var item in q)
{
    ListViewItem listItem = new ListViewItem();
    listItem.Text = item.Name;
    listItem.SubItems.Add(item.Phone);
    listView1.Items.Add(listItem);
}
```